# Copy paste range from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, paste

I tried my code to copy from N3:Y34 to A1 on the new sheet "Calculated values" but it didn't work. I have tried `.Paste` and `.PasteSpecial` but nothing changes.

[image: It only shows this on the new sheet]

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "Calculated Values"

'Copy the data
ActiveSheet.Range("N3:Y34").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Calculated Values").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A1").Select
'Paste in the target destination
Sheets("Calculated Values").PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the below and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'Check if sheet excist
    If Sheet_Exists("Calculated Values") = False Then

        Worksheets.Add().Name = "Calculated Values"

    End If

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Copy with formats
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N3:Y34").Copy .Worksheets("Calculated Values").Range("A1")
        'Copy only values
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N3:Y34").Copy
        .Worksheets("Calculated Values").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub

Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean

    Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

    Sheet_Exists = False

    For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
            Sheet_Exists = True
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I have tried your code after modifying the "Sheet1" to the name of my sheet. It still gives me a runtime error '9', subscript out of range.

Comment: ate which line??

Comment: Error 1004, at `.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N3:Y34").Copy .Worksheets("Calculated Values").Range("A1")`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Error, after checking through my I have found my mistake. This should be the correct code: 

`ActiveSheet.Range("N3:Y34").Copy
    
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "Calculated Values"
    
    'Activate the destination worksheet
    Sheets("Calculated Values").Activate
    'Select the target range
    Range("A1").Select
    'Paste in the target destination
    Sheets("Calculated Values").PasteSpecial
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: Glad to help. if the answer helps vote to help others with the same